# gcc disable ALL warnings for a few lines of code

Tags: c, gcc

I have the same problem as described by Jonathon Reinhart here:
[Temporarily disable gcc warning on redefinition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159978/temporarily-disable-gcc-warning-on-redefinition)

That is because I have to use thrid party libraries (*C only*) which throws tons of warnings like this

```
Warning "__always_inline" redefined [enabled by default]
```

What I want is something like this:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-W???"
  #include "someheader.h"
  #include "otherheader.h"
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Is there a way to *disable* warnings by gcc which are *enabled by default* with a

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored
```

**EDIT:**
here is the block causing the warning (file: compiler.h):

```
#if defined(__CC_ARM)
#   define __always_inline   __forceinline
#elif (defined __GNUC__)
#   define __always_inline   inline __attribute__((__always_inline__))
#elif (defined __ICCARM__)
#   define __always_inline   _Pragma("inline=forced")
#endif
```

Comment: it's rude of them to use reserved names like that. Have you contacted the vendors of the libraries?  You oould ask them to supply header files suitable for use with a C compiler.  or you could attack the supplied headers with sed or similar and change the macros to not use reserved names.

Comment: "sweep the bugs under the rug" seems like a sub-optimal solution to this problem

Comment: The vendor (Atmel) is informed: http://asf.atmel.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=3486 You're right. Sweeping bugs isn't the best solution, but fixing bugs like redefinition of exact the same *__always_inline* lines for every new version of the library again and again is even worse.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by undefining all lines where __always_inline was defined. :-(
Thanks Jasen for helping!